# Declaring and initializing a parameter from a Promise result from onNgInit (Angular2)

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a parameter called 'customer' which is initialized from a Promise request upon rendering of the view

```js
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  customer: Customer;

  /***
   * Returns a Customer by id
   * @param id
   */
  getCustomer(id: number): void {
    this.customerService.find(id)
      .then(customer => {
        this.customer = customer;
      });
  }

  /***
   * Init function
   */
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      let customerId = Number(params['id']);
      this.getCustomer(customerId);
    });
  }

}
```

My problem is that in the view I have this

> Current customer name is {{customer.name}}

which is receiving an exception stating that it cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

What is the right way of declaring a Component variable and initializing it on ngOnInit?

Comment: Duplicate, this question has been asked many times. The `customer` property is async and therefore not defined the first time you try to access it. You should write something like `{{customer?.name}}`

Comment: I knew I wasn't the only one! Thanks for your help!